# Jittery Behavior on First Scroll in React Header Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

### Description

I'm encountering an issue with the header component in my React based next.js web application. Upon the initial load of the page, when I first scroll, there's a noticeable jittery behavior before the header hides as intended. Once this initial jittery behavior occurs, the header behaves perfectly fine for subsequent scrolls.

```
function Header() {
    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
    const { theme } = useTheme();
    const [prevScrollPos, setPrevScrollPos] = useState(0);
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = () => {
            const currentScrollPos = window.scrollY;
            setVisible(prevScrollPos > currentScrollPos || currentScrollPos < 200);
            setPrevScrollPos(currentScrollPos);
        };

        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

        return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }, [prevScrollPos]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setMounted(true);
    }, []);

    if (!mounted) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <>
            {(theme === 'light' || theme === 'undefined' || theme === null) && visible && <LightHeader />}
            {theme === 'dark' && visible && <DarkHeader />}
        </>
    )
}
```

(I am using next-themes for theme switching. The mounting logic is to mitigate hydration error)

I suspect I might be missing a crucial React concept or best practice here. Could someone please provide insights into what might be causing this jittery behavior on the first scroll and how I can resolve it? Would de-bouncing help in this scenario? Additionally, could this issue be related to React Snapshot?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

---

[warning suggests that I read scroll anchoring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor/Guide_to_scroll_anchoring)

Comment: Scroll anchoring was disabled in a scroll container because of too many consecutive adjustments (10) with too little total distance (0 px average, 0 px total).

this is consoled out as well

Comment: Browser scrolling (*and mouse events in general*) are quite noisy. Have you tried using a passive event listener? Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this scrolling issue that we could inspect live?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with scroll not able to anchor due to dynamically adding and removing the header component. I was rendering either the header component or null which was affecting the height of the document.

I mitigated this issue by using visibility: visible and hidden such that it is still in the document flow but hidden.

NOTE: I still don't know why the issue resolves itself after initial jitter tho. Is it because the height of the header is saved by the document?